# Django ManyToManyField connected to field inside another model. (Project Management)

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-templates, django-views

I have a SchoolClass with Members. I now want to make a Project that connects to some of the members. How do I do that?

```
class SchoolKlass(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    members = models.ManyToManyField(UserProfile, blank=True,related_name='a')

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = 'Klasser'

    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.username

class Project(models.Model):
    members = models.ManyToManyField(SchoolKlass.members, blank=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=1000)
    schoolKlass = models.ForeignKey(SchoolKlass, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

As you can see, I want to access SchoolKlass.members inside the manytomany relationship of the Project model.

Comment: I am not really following what you would want to do here. Exactly how would that work? Do you want a *ternary* relation?

Comment: Yes i want to assign a project to some of the members in the SchoolClass

Comment: Like SchoolKlass.members

Answer (score 0):

user circular import ..

```
class SchoolKlass(models.Model):
name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
members = models.ManyToManyField(UserProfile, blank=True,related_name='a')

class Meta:
    verbose_name_plural = 'Klasser'

    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.username

class Project(models.Model):
    members = models.ManyToManyField("SchoolKlass.members", blank=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=1000)
    schoolKlass = models.ForeignKey(SchoolKlass, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

provide the "appname.model" on relation filed. don't forget the quote,

Comment: In that case it would be 'myClass.SchoolKlass.members' and that dosen't work

Comment: no in this case that would be "appname.SchoolKlass"